# insufficient storage space when running updates on S4 mini

Tags: sd-card, insufficient-memory, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

my s4 mini keeps trying to run an update but everytime I allow it to, a message pops up saying that I dont have the 539mb (or something like that) in my internal memory or sd card. But I have deleted and moved a lot of things around and now have over 600mb in my internal and still over 6Gb on the sd card.

What do I do?

Comment: The same thing troubled me yesterday on my friends phone. Then I have cleared much more than needed, so I was able to proceed, but then got another error: "Can't read SD card" or something like that. Installations were set to install on internal memory so i don't know the reason of this error.

Comment: David, you might wish to check our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). Next to some basic explanations, it also contains some first-aid and links to related information. See if that helps, and then please [edit] your question to include what you've tried and where you're stuck – or [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) if you were able to solve your issue. Good luck!